# selenium automation in java

Tags: java, excel, selenium, batch-file

We would need to run multiple batchfiles in sequential order. However before running them we need to create unique test data (in Xls) sheets for respective batch file test.
Is there any way to handle this in selenium(code is developed in java).

Right now creating test data is Xls and then running single batch file does have much manual efforts for each of test.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: Just use Apache poi library to populate excel with test data.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium used to automate web browser. Therefore your answer is NO